# Can't connect to PostgreSQL database on remote server

Tags: database, postgresql, networking, ip, psql

**Context**

I created a PostgreSQL database on a windows remote server.
By using OpenVPN I can connect to the remote server on my local computer.
The remote server now receives ping packets via the IPv4 default gateway IP.
The IPv4 address IP doesn't receive any ping packets as all traffic goes trough the gateway IP (I assume).

pg_hba.conf (on local computer and remote server):

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                    scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0              md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                scram-sha-256
host    all             all             ::0/0                  md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

postgresql.conf (on local computer and remote server):

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

**Issue**

I can't connect to the PostgreSQL database on the remote server with the gateway IP. I'm also not sure if that's the IP that I should be using.

The command:

```
psql -U postgres -h [gateway IP of the server] -d [name of the database on the server]
```

The output:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "[gateway IP of the server]", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I also tried putting the exact gateway IP in pg_hba.conf, but it didn't help.
Does anyone know the solution for this issue?

Comment: Either the IP address does not exist, or a firewall is swallowing your packets. At any rate, it is a network configuration problem. But first, run `SHOW listen_addresses;` to see if the setting is actually the way you want.

Comment: SHOW listen_adresses returns '*' as I've configured in postgresql.conf.

Comment: Great. Then it is certainly a network problem.

Comment: The gateway IP receives packets from the ping which means it does exists. But I still get the psql error as described above.

Comment: It is the combination of the IP, the port that counts. The error indicates that either: 1)  The port is not open. 2) The server is not running 3) Both 1) & 2).

Comment: I can connect now! I didn't restart the PostgreSQL service on the server after modifying the pg_hba.conf...